# Rotating both in local and world coordinate system

Tags: math, graphics, rotation, linear-algebra

Let's consider a simple case where we have an object with transformation matrix and then we do simple transoformations:

1. rotate the x axis through X1 angle -> A matrix
2. rotate the y axis through Y1 angle -> B matrix
3. rotate the x axis through X2 angle -> C matrix

In usual case I would do C * B * A and that would be the end of a story. But what it does, as we know, is applying new transformation in local coordinate system created by previous transformation. I don't like it.

What I would like to do in some certain situations is to rotate in local and some other times in world coordinate system. What I mean is that if I have matrix M = B * A (but I don't have X1 and Y1 angles available; all I have is M) and I would like to apply C *in the world coordinate system* then the output new transformation matrix would have the following:

- x rotation = X1 + X2
- y rotation = Y1

Is there any way to achieve it?

**EDIT**

I think I explained in wrongly.

Let's assume we have an object A at position described by matrix M. M has rotation, scaling and translation. I'd like to rotate the object along axes positioned in the center of object A but parallel to axes of a base coordinate system. After all I would also like the object to stay at (x,y,z) in base coordinate system.

Answer (score 2):

> In usual case I would do C * B * A and that would be the end of a story. But what it does, as we know, is applying new transformation in local coordinate system created by previous transformation.

**Incorrect.**

Consider a test point `p`. The coordinates of `B * A * p` in the local coordinate system of `B * A` are simply the world-space components of `p` – because a transformation is just a change of coordinate system.

So replacing `p` with `C * p` applies the transformation *locally*, i.e.:

- `C * (B * A)` applies `C` in the **world** coordinate system
- `(B * A) * C` applies `C` in the **local** coordinate system of `B * A`

---

**EDIT**

To rotate an object around its position `p`:

- Translate by `-p`
- Apply the desired rotation matrix `C`
- Translate by `+p` to restore the original position

The final matrix is `T * C * inv(T) * M`, where `T` is a translation by `p`, and `M` is the original matrix. `p` is given by the last column of `M`.

Comment: I think I explained it wrongly. More details in the edit.

Comment: @Kamisama you should have mentioned translation before. Edited.